# How to auto import all Stripe classes into CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, stripe-payments

How do I import all necessary classes from Stripe PHP SDK (2.1.0) into CakePHP (2.6.1)?

I have added a submodule for the Stripe and cloned it into app/Vendor/Stripe

My code looks like this:

```
<?php

App::uses('Stripe', 'Vendor/Stripe/lib');

// Secret API Key for Stripe
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');


class BillingController extends AppController {

// My methods

}


?>
```

and I get:

```
Fatal Error
Error: Class 'Stripe\Stripe' not found  
File: /Projects/Web/admin.example.io/app/Controller/BillingController.php   
Line: 6
```

Comment: Where is your Stripe folder located ?

Comment: app/Vendor/Stripe/lib/Stripe.php

Comment: Stop trying to reinvent the wheel, use composer.

Comment: well, if I use the composer, how do I import the require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

Comment: See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#installing-cakephp-with-composer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `import()` while using vendor , not `uses()`
like

```
App::import('Vendor', 'Stripe', array('file' => 'Stripe' . DS .'lib' . DS . 'Stripe.php'));
```

Here DS is constant for `/`.

You should follow cakephp naming convention like import() `Must` be used while using Vendor package . While using other classes such as controller you can use uses() but not here in your situation.

**Updated :**

Now **steps** , you need to follow as it is more specific to your problem :

1.Install using composer.

2.Now import installed package/vendor using

`App::import('Vendor', 'autoload', array('file' => 'Stripe' . DS .'vendor' . DS . 'autoload.php'));`

Comment: That works on the initial method that sets the key, so thanks a lot, almost there, but if I try to retrieve the list of customers through pretty much second method advertised in the Stripe documentation (\Stripe\Customer::all()), I get Fatal Error
Error: Class 'Stripe\Customer' not found ... the question really was how do I import all the necessary classes, could you help?

Comment: and if I subsequently import the Customer, it fails on Error: Class 'Stripe\ApiResource' not found. Which unfortunately for whatever reason I can't import in the same way? :(

Comment: Did you load Customer class ? as you are calling static method `all()` .

Comment: Yeah, I did .... App::import('Vendor', 'Stripe', array('file' => 'Stripe' . DS .'lib' . DS . 'Stripe.php'));
App::import('Vendor', 'Customer', array('file' => 'Stripe' . DS .'lib' . DS . 'Customer.php'));
App::import('Vendor', 'ApiResource', array('file' => 'Stripe' . DS .'lib' . DS . 'ApiResource.php'));

Comment: Did you read completely ? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php it tells way to work with it.

Comment: yes, I did ... I haven't used composer, I have cloned the files in as I have mentioned as a submodule so I keep the way thirdparty files are managed consistent ... That is really my question as the github page is talking about autoload file but I need to make it working without it ... or at least try

Comment: Hmm so other classes are properly included , we need to find what is issue with ApiResource class !

Comment: the right answer is .... install using composer and than .... App::import('Vendor', 'autoload', array('file' => 'Stripe' . DS .'vendor' . DS . 'autoload.php'));

// Secret API Key for Stripe
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_asdfasfasfsafsdfsaf');

So if you want to modify your answer, I'll accept it as I wouldn't finish it without you :)

Comment: @Ondrej , Hi is the answer fine ?

Comment: There is no need for this `App::import` fiddling, you can just use `require` in the bootstrap. All that needs to be done is documented, and already linked in the comments above: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#installing-cakephp-with-composer**

Answer (score 0):

You should include the init.php file.

The directory structure of the zipped file is something like this:

`stripe-php
 - libs/
 - data/
 - test/
 - init.php`

Instead of including the PHP files in the libs folder, just include init.php.